# How can I specify order when getting all products of a given type?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am getting a list of all products for a specific type within commerce. All is well & working great.

I would like to know how I can dictate order. In my case, I always want the cheapest product first; the most expensive last. A perfect example would be if I were purchasing a level of membership in that "level" is a product.

So on my product index page:
`mysite.com/memberships`

I want to always have the cheapest membership listed first, all the way up to the most expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an element, it has the same `order` criteria as entries, assets, &c. So you should have no problem using `order('defaultPrice')` in your criteria. That's for price low-to-high. For high-to-low, you add `desc` to the criteria. So: `order('defaultPrice desc')`.

Comment: `defaultPrice` That's what I was missing. Thank you!